# how can method "getSystemService" be used directly in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-broadcast

I got this problem: `getSystemService` defines in `Context` class, so I assume it is called when `context.getSystemService`. I can't understand the following code where `getSystemService` is called directly in `BroadcastReceiver`. I run the code and no error show!

Codes:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ……
 class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager)
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable()) 
    {
    Toast.makeText(context, "network is available",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "network is unavailable",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `NetworkChangeReceiver`  is an inner class of `MainActivity`.
You are using the Activity context.
Try using NetworkChangeReceiver in a new file(not sub class), you will see what happens.

`MainActivity.this` though its referring to your own class which extends Activity class but the base class (Activity) also extends Context class, so it can be used to offer activity context.

Comment: In this case, getSystemService is called in BroadcastReceiver(a inner class). So by default, getSystemService means this.getSystemService. doesn't  "this" point to NetworkChangReceiver？  I am little bit confused about "context",sorry about that

Comment: @SamuelChan change `NetworkChangeReceiver` to a `static` class and you will see...

Answer (score 15):

`getSystemService()` is part of the `Context`.  You need to use the `Context` you receive in your `onReceive()` method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
}
```